# The elements in my navbar bug out when I transition to different elements. How can I prevent this from happening?

Tags: html, css

So here's my website: https://www.tiffanymkoval.com

I set a background image for the elements in my navbar, using this code:

```
.navbar-inner nav ul li.current-menu-item a span, 
.navbar-inner nav ul li.current_page_item a span, 
.nav_8egh8uzbk .navbar-inner nav ul li.wrap-focus a span { 
  background-image: url(https://www.tiffanymkoval.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/08/circle.svg);
  background-position: 0% 600%;
  background-size: 100%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  text-decoration: none;
  z-index: 99;
  margin: 10px !important;
  padding: 10px !important;
}
```

However, the image seems to transform when I'm clicking on another element. How could I prevent this from happening? Ideally I'd like to have it so the image simply appears - without all the weird jumps.

Answer (score 0):

You can set the image to pseudo selector as `:after` and position it absolute under the span. That way you can transition the opacity of it.

```
.navbar-inner nav ul li.current-menu-item a span, 
.navbar-inner nav ul li.current_page_item a span, 
.nav_8egh8uzbk .navbar-inner nav ul li.wrap-focus a span { 
   position: relative;
   display: inline-block;
}

.navbar-inner nav ul li.current-menu-item a span:after, 
.navbar-inner nav ul li.current_page_item a span:after, 
.nav_8egh8uzbk .navbar-inner nav ul li.wrap-focus a span:after { 
  background-image: url(https://www.tiffanymkoval.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/08/circle.svg);
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-position: 50% 50%;
  background-size: 100% 100%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove all transitions from your link elements (except for that hover transition).

Size changes (from 0 to its full size) upon loading the page are causing the weird jumping.